# I need help for counter integral please

Tags: integration

I want to solve this integral 
$$J(\omega)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\gamma_i\lambda^2}{(\lambda^2+(\omega_i-\Delta-\omega)^2)} $$
$$N(\omega)=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{-\omega t}{T}}-1}$$

$$\int_0^\infty J(\omega)N(\omega)$$
there are three poles I don't know how I get rid of pole on zero (pole in N(w))
would you please help me?

Comment: Looking at the range of integration , it seems difficult to apply contour integration to this problem. Maybe you should have a look at the Binet/Hermite integrals,